# Trying to override View's views-exposed-form with my own, however it will not show my theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I've copied over from the view's module's theme folder: views-exposed-form.tpl.php to themes/mytheme/views (also tried themes/mytheme) and renamed as views-exposed-filter--commerce_reports_products.tpl.php (and views-exposed-filter--commerce-reports-products.tpl.php).

After flushing cache and re-scanning the templates in the view, it still will not show. If I edit the original views-exposed-form.tpl.php it will show the changes.

I got the view name from the Theme's link in the view: views-view-field--commerce-reports-products.tpl.php

Does anyone know what else I might have to do, or why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Views does not automatically provide template suggestions for the exposed filter, like it does for the fields themselves. So you will need to do a little bit more for this :

1. Use the the [devel_themer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to find out what function/template is theming that exposed filter
2. Create a preprocessor for that theme function/template. In your preprocessor you can then insert dynamic template suggestions that will fire off based on any condition you want. You can create this preprocessor either in your custom theme's template.php file or in one of your custom modules. This [D.O. article](http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions) will guide you with creating the dynamic template suggestion.

Assuming that you will be displaying different Views displays based on a URL path. If this were the case, then you can use Drupal's arg() function in your preprocessor to figure out what is the View display that you are currently displaying, and construct your template suggestion using that information.

Once you've setup your suggestions properly, then Drupal would automatically call the appropriate template, you have different filter templates based on the path.

Comment: So I tried number 1, the devel module showed me the name should be views-exposed-form--commerce-reports-products--page.tpl.php and that did nothing for me, 

the second one I tried adding this: 
function thevault_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$variables ){
  watchdog('notice', "test");
  dpm($variables, "va ");
}
in the template.php file and that also did nothing for me.